# Can I put more then 1 thread in swingUtilities.invokeLater?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingutilities

I don't know how to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` precisely, but in my application, the panels run in different Runnables, and `swingUtilities.invokeLater` accepts Runnables in the argument, but if I put a thread inside the thread of swingUtilities.invokeLater, it will work inside the "SwingUtilities thread-safe AWT/Swing concept"? and can I put more then 1 thread? because I have panels/threads to run inside 1 JFrame.

Comment: Not sure what you mean that your panels run in different threads. it makes no sense.   There is a single event dispatcher thread which handles all events and graphic responses. The 'invokeLater' adds events to this thread, i.e. after you done a long task in an arbitrary thread, you signal a gui component to update by invoking correct (short) update commands with invokeLater. They will be added to the end of the event queue.

Comment: You're confused as to what `invokeLater` does. It does **not** take a Thread as argument but rather a Runnable, and it queues it on to the Swing event thread to be run on this single event thread. If you want to do background threading, use a SwingWorker, and create multiple workers if need be. Do read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to gain a better understanding of this.

Comment: Also your question is lacking in essential details and code, and it's hard to give you a specific answer without your improving it. Please have a look at [ask] for more on how to ask a decent question.

Comment: Also please have a look at [these similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+swing+multithreading) and their answers.

Comment: I will do a example code of this question and a problem with CountDownLatch that I have in the invokeLater that 
"block the interface"

Comment: You really want to take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) - Swing is single thread AND not thread safe. You should NEVER modify the UI (directly or indirectly) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: *"CountDownLatch that I have in the invokeLater that "block the interface""* - If you're running `CountDownLatch` within the context of the EDT - then yes, I imagine it would block the UI

Comment: But how can I use CountDownLatch if my Frame is inside a Runnable in invokeLater, like here: https://i.imgur.com/RPFv60d.png I need to use CountDown to freeze the runnable and make the panel work without remove the panel like the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swing only 1 thread (the event dispatch thread) may do updates to the user interface (all Swing UI components of the complete application). Do all the updates on user interface with a runnable that is passed into that invokeLater (or invokeAndWait) method.

Don't do calculations / other tasks in this runnable, because that can slowdown/block your user interface.

There is no maximum number of runnables you may pass into that SwingUtilities methods. All of them are executed by the event dispatch thread.